# Potential is with respect to what

Tags: electrostatics, potential

When we say a body has "high" electric potential and "low" electric potential, to what potential is it with respect to?

Comment: Depends upon where have you read it ...I think

Comment: For electric field,  potential at a point is defined as work done in bringing a unit positive charge from infinite distance to that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we use the term *electrical potential* we actually always mean a potential difference. The absolute value of the electrical potential has no physical meaning since we can never measure it. We can only measure potential differences. Technically the potential has a gauge symmetry, though this is possibly getting in deeper than your question warrants.

The electrical potential difference has a very simple physical meaning because it is just an energy that is the work done to move a unit charge. For example [in your previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/323433/in-capacitor-is-potential-or-potential-difference-is-used) you asked about the potential of an isolated sphere. To calulate this we simple take a test charge $q$ and calculate the work done to move this charge from infinity to the surface of the sphere. Then we divide this work by the charge $q$ and the result is the potential i.e. the work per unit charge.

Alternatively, and again going back to your previous question, the potential difference between the two plates of a capacitor is just the work done in moving our test charge $q$ from one plate to the other divided by $q$.

Comment: Looks like you check the entire history of the person before answering.. Nice answer though.

Comment: @AlphaRomeo It's possible he recognized the similar question from earlier.  It happens to me often enough.